# IIS 7 not recognizing svc file

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7

I'm trying to publish a webservice using WCF on IIS7.

I've created a Site for this project, and I created an Application too as [MSDN suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx#Y521). I can open html files in my browser from the created folder, but I get 404.3 error (The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration) if I try to access the svc file of my service. I've read that I should run servicemodelreg to install the missing handlers for the svc files. After I did I got an error saying that the handler has a bad module.

I checked the following stuff every time:

- IIS is turned on
- ASP.NET is turned on
- There is a handler for the svc files

I ran out of ideas...

Comment: What are you seeing in the event logs?

Comment: Do you have a `/bin` folder, and is the services binary in there?

Comment: Try to run aspnet_regiis.exe -i and set the ApplciationPool of the application to Framework 4.

Comment: @vorrtex: Yes, aspnet_regiis was the missing link! It is weird, because I did the same steps on my pc and this problem didn't occur, but when I tried to do it again on a laptop it did. Anyway, if you post this as an answer I'll mark it!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It happens if IIS is installed after .NET Framework and Visual Studio, so it is necessary to register ASP.Net. If to install IIS at first, there will be no such problems.

But the solution is simple: open `Visual Studio Command Promt` and type this command

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with more detailed information about this command and its parameters.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with Windows 8. The above isn't supported unfortunately. You need to go to Control Panel, Turn Windows features on or off and make sure the features you need under .NET 3.5 and 4.5 are ticked.

Comment: Yes, in Windows 8 it has changed, but WHY? It's beyond me why Microsoft keeps changing simple fundamental stuff like this, into the convoluted add/remove features monstrosity, where by the way .NET 4 is completely missing (it's supposed to mean that ticking .NET 4.5 means .NET 4, but why all this mess, instead of the simple aspnet_regiis command).

Comment: @Visar They probably decided to create a wizard so that people can see UI. But instead of adding it as an alternative way and keep both ways of configuration, they removed command line tools. Very unexpected.

Answer (score 27):

On windows 8, run `DISM.exe` in order to enable `WCF`:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

Or if you are setting up everything using Server manager Dashboard's Add Roles and Features Wizard do not forget to check "HTTP Activation" under WCF Services

[image]

Comment: i.e. do not forget to enable "HTTP Activation" under WCF feature list from role and feature setup wizard.. thanks!

Comment: This works in Windows Server 2012 when you do not have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 14):

Do the following steps to **enable SVC File handling under IIS** on **Windows 10**

1. Press Window Key + R (It will pop up **Run** command, Type **optionalfeatures** and press enter.
2. It will bring program features wizard. **Ensure that following options are selected** as shown in the snapshot.

**Follow Steps Mentioned in the following Snapshots**

[image: Snapshot 1 Showing the Windows Features Required to Turn On]

[image: Snapshot 2 Showing to turn on More Features]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Great post! +1 for the graphics

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 8 to enable WCF had to run these commands in an administrator started Visual Studio command prompt:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45
```

Comment: I did uninstall first (with "DISM /Online /Disable-Feature") then after that I reinstalled and worked!