# IIS 7.5 Handler Mappings for svc (wcf) with .multiple dot net frameworks (aspnet_regiis.exe)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, svc

I have a 2008 server which does not have svc listed in Handler Mappings in IIS. I believe that running aspnet_regiis.exe will add the these (as per [so 4932722](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932722/iis-7-not-recognizing-svc-file).

But that .exe exists under:

- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5"
- "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

Which should I chose?  (my guess would be the both the v4.0's versions)

Related to this...

Looking at a couple other machines that have .svc listed but ...

one points to: `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`

the other points to: `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll`

Can you have multiple handler mapping for svc pointing to different frameworks?

Thanks,
DF