# WCF Problem Encountered: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, wcf

**The Problem**

I am attempting to create a Rest service using WCF. I have created a WCF class in my call stack namespace called "Coronado.HUB" as shown below. When I make an http request to the service I get a 404 error.

**The Source Code**

```
using Coronado.HUB.Model;
using Coronado.HUB.Service;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Coronado.HUB
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Driver By ID
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDriverService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        Driver GetDriverById(Guid id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Driver Object By ID
    /// </summary>
    public class DriverService : IDriverService
    {
        public Driver GetDriverById(Guid id)
        {
            return DriverServiceProvider.Instance.GetDriverById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Accordingly, in my ASP.NET project, I have added the following DriverService.svc file with the following reference

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Coronado.HUB.DriverService" %>
```

**The Configuration**

Finally, I added the following configuration to my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <service name="Coronado.HUB.DriverService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Coronado.HUB.IDriverService" behaviorConfiguration="RestService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/XXX/DriverService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestService">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue for a day and a half and I cannot get it to work. I would be grateful if someone could show me where I have gone wrong. Thank you for your time and consideration.

**-- Update --**

The URL I am trying to resolve is as follows

```
http://localhost/XXX/DriverService.svc/GetDriverById?id=F200A17F-9E03-41EB-90FB-01B8665246BB
```

Comment: Which project template did you use in your project? I would like to know more about your project structure. It appears to me you didn’t use WCF Service application project templates.
Therefore, it might be invalid to program the service implementation class.
Besides, the specified base address is invalid. It should be configured in the IIS site-binding module.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I did try to use VS project templates but ran into issues. I am using another implementation done a couple of few years back that is currently working w/o issue. I used these patterns verbatim to implement the pattern demonstrated above. Granted, this implementation is not consistent with VS templates, it seamed to be an efficient implementation. Perhaps I should try to get this working with existing project templates.

Comment: Yes, this implementation is an efficient implementation. It has nothing with the project template. After I tried to reproduce your issue, it proves to work properly. How do you host your service? Are you sure that the service address is right?

Comment: I was able to determine that WCF was not properly registered with IIS. Once I registered and activated HTTP under WCF options for .Net 4.7 via the OS program files & features on my local machine - it worked. Thank you very much for your feedback - it was very helpful in that I got both this older implementation to work as well as the VS project Template to work. I'm debating whether to use the VS project templates or stick with the original implementation. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I encountered was caused because WCF was not registered with IIS. It is my understanding, pre .Net 4.0 - this is done via the command line. In my case, I used Programs & Features. This cleared up the problem

For additional information ref: [IIS 7 not recognizing svc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932722/iis-7-not-recognizing-svc-file)