# Webservice XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: http://localhost/Service1.svc Line Number 1, Column 1: ^

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I'm having a problem with my webservice when I uploade it to iis. I keep receiving this error even tho I haven't made any changes whatsoever to it, but the live version on site works. I don't know if I'm maybe publishing it wrong? Everything I've found on this is about ASP.Net, which hasn't hellped me much at all.

My publish settings are as follows

[image]

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what it's supposed to be:

[image]

Comment: What it the content returned when you visit the SVC service with the web browser?

Comment: The IIS may be lacking the WCF components of you may need a registration of asp.net, check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932722/iis-7-not-recognizing-svc-file)

Comment: If it can run in VS but not in IIS, it is likely that some features are missing. You can check the link provided by Cleptus to ensure that the features required by web-services are installed.

Comment: If there is still a problem, you can use FRT to troubleshoot the cause of this problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis